# How to make android Volley request with body like following

Tags: android, android-volley

I have following request in postman and I want to implement it in volley, android.

Any solution?

following is request header

[image: request body]

Following is request body

[image: request header]

Comment: What type of solution do you want? How to request Volley with the JSON or how to parse the JSON? Your question is unclear.  @Muhammad

Comment: I want to make a string request

Comment: Paste your JSON response will parse it using the Volley network call @Muhammad

Comment: {
"success": true,
"user": {
    "id": 342,
    "title": "demo",
    "gender": "male",
    "description": "test desc",
    "age_range": "55-64"
},
"message": "CareTeam Added"

Comment: this is what I want to get

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan go through below Parsing Json Data code

Comment: @Deepak, where I get error response when I follow your code

Comment: You mean to say sucess:true or false?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan have edited my answer please check

Comment: Check my code at once.Are you sending arraylist data to server?If yes,you shold parse it first.

Comment: @RahulKushwaha..the part that confuses me is that whether body is hashmap or a list... I can't figure it out through postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this .Add headers data like this.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = APICLient.BASE_URL+"api/Admin_controller/getProspectField";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jo=new JSONObject(response);
                            Boolean status=jo.getBoolean("success");

                            JSONArray ja=jo.getJSONArray("user");

                             // write your logic here...
                            for (int i=0;i<ja.length();i++){
                                JSONObject jsonObject=ja.getJSONObject(i);
                                String pname=jsonObject.getString("p_name");
                                String pType=jsonObject.getString("p_type");


                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders(){
                HashMap <String,String> params=new HashMap<>();
                params.put("authorization","put_authorization_key_here");

                return params;
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getParams(){
                HashMap <String,String> params=new HashMap<>();
                params.put("care_team[]",team);
                ........................
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Json Parsing with volley:

```
private void userLogin() {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URLs.URL_LOGIN,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {

                                try {
                                    //converting response to json object
                                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                                    //if no error in response
                                    if (obj.getBoolean("status")) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        //getting the user from the response
                                        JSONObject userJson = obj.getJSONObject("user");

                                        //creating a new user object
                                        User user = new User(
                                                userJson.getInt("cid"),
                                                userJson.getInt("company_id"),
                                                userJson.getString("name"),
                                                userJson.getString("email")

                                        );

                                        //storing the user in shared preferences
                                        SharedPreferenceManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).userLogin(user);

                                        //starting the profile activity
                                        finish();
                                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), obj.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                    }

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                     e.printStackTrace();
                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }

                        })


                {
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put("company_id",companyid );
                        params.put("email", username);
                        params.put("password", password);
                        return params;
                    }


                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        headers.put("x-api-key", "swicons@1019");
                        return headers;
                    }

                };

                stringRequest.setShouldCache(false);
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
            }
```

Comment: let me check again